# What is the correct way of creating a Closure or IIFE for handling an onclick event in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, iife

I am trying to make use of the `this` object in an event handler but I keep getting an undefined error concerning the this object.

I am using ReactJS and Redux as well

```
class Chat extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.setUpChats   = this.setUpChats.bind(this);
        this.setChattingTo= this.setChattingTo.bind(this);
    }

    setChattingTo(){

        return function(){
            //breaks here can't access the this object
            this.props.chattingToUser(user);
        } 
    }

    setUpChats(){
        //map inside a map to g 
        var chats = _.map(chatCollection, function(key, value){

            return (<ul> _.map(key, function(i){
                return (
                    <li 
                        onClick={this.setChattingTo(user[i])}
                    >
                     user[i].username
                    </li>       
            }.bind(this))</ul>)

        }.bind(this));    
    }

}
```

So my question is how to access the `this` object in the setChattingTo function so that it runs correctly when clicked?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `.bind()` in the event handler itself. You need to use fat arrow syntax `_.map(chatCollection, (key, value) => {}` in order to implicitly bind `this`. Or you can do `const that = this;` above your map.

If you're using a more recent stage of babel you can also get rid of the constructor binding of `this` and just do an implicit bind in the function definition.

```
setUpChats = () => {}
```